# How to input words_with_underscores into an org-table?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I want to place text like `site_volume` into a column of an org-table.  Outside of tables I would wrap the text with =equals_signs= to guarantee the underscores within were displayed literally, but doing that inside tables causes the text to be treated as a formula and it gets replaced by **ERROR!**.  Is there alternate literal syntax within tables?

Comment: What problem do you see when you use underscores in text in your table? Are you talking about a problem (like subscripting occurring) when you export the table containing text with underscores? If so, see [#+OPTIONS: ^:{}](http://orgmode.org/manual/Subscripts-and-superscripts.html)

Comment: Thanks!  I forgot about this option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the tilde (~) to quote the values instead of equals. It's for quoting things that don't need to be displayed in a fixed-width font.

Comment: Nice!. Where this is specifically listed ? All I found is :(info "(org) Emphasis and monospace")

Comment: In my Emacs that info page says:

"You can make words *bold*, /italic/, _underlined_, `=code=' and
`~verbatim~', and, if you must, `+strike-through+'. Text in the code
and verbatim string is not processed for Org mode specific syntax; it
is exported verbatim."

Answer (score 1):

Or use the shell backslash to 'quote' the underscore to avoid Org-mode interpreting it as markup, eg:

```
| Variable              | File    |
| some\_variable        | test.c  |
| some\_other\_variable | test2.c |
```

In combination with the following this can make things pretty readable in Emacs Org-mode buffers, even without exporting to HTML/PDF:

```
(setq org-pretty-entities t)
(setq org-hide-emphasis-markers t)
```